# In App Purchases: Give User purchased item after purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

this is kind of a two part question that ties into each-other and would not be worth asking seperately

**First Problem**

so i just finished a guide tutorial on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3hJ0rY1NNw) about in-app purchases and he mostly covered the actual payment and restoration of bought items etc.

but the one thing he didnt cover that i actually needed was a way to actually give the Buyer (in my case in-game coins) the purchased item

here is the file with all the purchase functions and other things

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class IAPService: NSObject {

    private override init() {}
    static let shared = IAPService()

    var products = [SKProduct]()
    var paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

func getProducts() {
    let products: Set = [IAPProduct.StackOfCoins.rawValue,
                         IAPProduct.PileOfCoins.rawValue,
                         IAPProduct.BoxOfCoins.rawValue,
                         IAPProduct.MountainOfCoins.rawValue,
                         IAPProduct.ContainerOfCoins.rawValue]
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()

    paymentQueue.add(self)
}

    func purchase(product: IAPProduct) {
        guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }).first else { return }
        let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
        paymentQueue.add(payment)


    }
}
extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        print(response.products)
        for product in response.products {
            print(product.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing: break
            default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
}
extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
    func status() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .deferred: return "deferred"
        case .failed: return "failed"
        case .purchased: return "purchased"
        case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
        case .restored: return "restored"
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the second file storing my products IDs

```
import Foundation
//crappy duck is the name of my game i am developing and these here represent increasing values of coins the user can buy

enum IAPProduct: String {
    case StackOfCoins = "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.StackOfCoins"
    case PileOfCoins = "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.PileOfCoins"
    case BoxOfCoins = "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.BoxOfCoins"
    case MountainOfCoins = "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.MountainOfCoins"
    case ContainerOfCoins = "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.ContainerOfCoins"

}
```

it works fine i can connect and access my products for sale (in-game coins) and all that but what i cannot figure out is how to change it so that it gives the user in-game coins based on the item he is buying

here is what im using to have the user actually buy stuff

this is in a collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        IAPService.shared.pruchase(product: .StackOfCoins)
    }
    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .PileOfCoins)
    }
    if indexPath.item == 2 {
        IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .BoxOfCoins)
    }
    if indexPath.item == 3 {
        IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .MountainOfCoins)
    }
    if indexPath.item == 4 {
        IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .ContainerOfCoins)
    }
}
```

**Second Problem**

i have the value **Coins** stored in UserDefaults and someone else in one of my previous questions warned me that it was a bad idea to have a purchaseable product stored in UserDefaults

what is a second option to UserDefaults that i can access, add to, and subtract from with in-app purchases and with in-game purchaseable products

**Summary**

in case my questions werent clear (if they werent let me know so i can edit them)

my first question is *how do i give the user the bought product after they purchased it*

and my second question is *another option to userDefaults value of **Coins** that is more secure then UserDefaults*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another case to the switch in `updatedTransactions`:

```
switch transaction.transactionState {
    case .purchased:
        let coinsValue = generateValue(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        //add a call to your function here
        break;
    case .purchasing: break
    default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

And call your method of adding coins in that case, with respect to the product that was bought.

Here is a method to get int from the identifier:

```
private func generateValue(_ identifier: String) -> Int
{
    switch identifier {
        case "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.StackOfCoins":
            return 1
        case "com.HucksCorp.Crappy-duck.PileOfCoins":
            return 2
        /// etc..
        default:
            return 0
    }
}
```

Regarding coins storage, you can sync them to a file, store in keychain or use server side storage, which probably is the best option.

Comment: thanks i will try this also is there no other way to have a value inaccessible from the hackers but is stored in-code?

Comment: There is absolutely no way of making your values hacker-proof, everything is breakable. But you can make their life harder, or even render their attempts unfeasible.

Comment: ok so new problem your switch case is working and i wrote a function that returns an Integer then saves it to UserDefaults **Coins** now how do i make it so that the value changes based on what cell the user clicks on

Comment: thanks very much for all your help i now have finished my app and can also launch tomorrow

Comment: how do i make it so that the integer value changes based on the product purchased

Comment: @E.Huckabee, create a new method with a `switch`, which returns a different integer value for each `transaction.payment.productIdentifier`.

Comment: could you edit your question with the suggested code?

Comment: @E.Huckabee, added an example of how you could get your value.

Comment: forgot to comment but i did figure it out but thanks anyway i really did appreciate your fast responses and helping me with all my problems if i could upvote and mark as correct more than once i would